# How to remove Angular empty <style> tag in header?

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I'm using Angular 8 and I'm having problem with it's `<style>`. I have an old question about [how to extract css into a single file in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327802/how-to-solve-violate-csp-directive-default-src-self-in-angular-8). We can definetely do that with a single configuration `extractCss` set to be `true`. However, if you don't style your components with "css module" in mind, then even if you can moving them out into a single file, it still won't work properly due to styles getting overriden. I have resolved all of that manually :(. I have even forked the only external library that we use `ng2-completer` to remove all of the component styles in this library. Now the only single issue left is this annoying empty `<style>`

[image]

First think come to my mind is to trace the source code to see if there is a single inline element dangling around. There is none, I've checked all the code (even in the `.svg` files). I've noticed that the `<style>` element is injected only when I'm navigating through `<router-outlet>`. I've tried commenting it out and voula, the `<style>` element is not there anymore.

I then comment out the `html` code that is navigated to by `<router-outlet>`, strangly, the problem's still remained.

I've googled like crazy and the only closet thing I've found out is the need for removing this empty `<style>` can be resolved if you use Angular server side rendering.
I cant found out if this is Angular issue or not as there is no related document.

All I need is to get rid of that empty `<style>` to completely remove all of the `CSP error logs` in browser's console.

I've tried updating the `ng2-completer` and the project to Angular 9, it resolves the issue but the clients don't want to upgrade because of the effor of testing the entire application again. One more reason is I don't know why it resolves the issue so I will not apply the solution since I don't know how it works.

Please help to suggest a solution or a workaround for this (this is needed because of CSP).

**Edit 1:** Like I said, I cant find any answers that are closed to this question. For example this one is not related to my question [Angular - How to remove  element from  after the component is destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311141/angular-how-to-remove-style-element-from-head-after-the-component-is-destr) as you can see in that question they completely ignored the empty `<style>` and we don't use component style (to avoid CSP issue).

**Edit 2:** It looks like this is not getting any attention from Angular team. :( 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31191

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How to remove <style> element from <head> after the component is destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311141/angular-how-to-remove-style-element-from-head-after-the-component-is-destr)

Comment: No, I've found out that one too. We don't use component style anymore, all style now is in a single css file and inject into DOM using `<link>`. The issue is that unexpected empty `<style>`.

Comment: You could try adding a dom breakpoint in chrome's debugger to see what is adding the `style` element

Comment: And if you manually delete the style tag from the debugger, does it work after? If yes, then you don't need server side rendering, you can just manipulate the dom to remove the style tag

Comment: Hi @David I know where is that code located but cannot make change, it's in Angular's core. If you run `ng serve` it will show a lot of CSP error logs, open source map and you can see something like this:
```
function applyToTag(style, options, obj) {
 ...
  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  }else{
    while (style.firstChild) {
      style.removeChild(style.firstChild);
    }

    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
}
```
The idea can be basically remove that `<style>` tag before browser "knows" that we have an inline style, but how?

Comment: Ok, but so if you remove it after the page is rendered, does it work?

Comment: It doesn't work if we remove `<style>` after the page is rendered, when the browser sees `<style>` in `<head>`, we are doomed :( .

Comment: @David I think I have to add this issue on Angular github page. I don't think it makes sense to add `<style>` when you know it's empty.